# transaction working without @EnableTransactionManagement

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am using spring boot with mybatis. I am not using spring data or anything but on my service if i use annotation like

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor= {Exception.class})
```

it is handling transaction.I have not specified anywhere to enable transaction management. How spring boot enable this. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring Boot does initiate the transaction autoconfigration if database source properties does exist.
See the `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration` code.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ JdbcTemplate.class, PlatformTransactionManager.class })
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.class)
public class DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration 

    // other code
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(
            DataSourceProperties properties) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(
                this.dataSource);
        if (this.transactionManagerCustomizers != null) {
            this.transactionManagerCustomizers.customize(transactionManager);
        }
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

The datasource properties are: `url`, `driverClassName`, `jndiName` etc.